# Validation Twitter Bootstrap with Django

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Django and Twitter Bootstrap. I am using the following code for validation. But I would like to add more validations. For example if a variable from Django is `false` to return 'Owner does not exist'. I tried the following but is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = {msg_owner|safe}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frm').bootstrapValidator({

        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            'owner': {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please enter the Owner'
                    }
                    test==false: {
                        message: 'Owner does not exist'
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the server side I do this:

```
def test(request):
    msg_owner = False
    return render_to_response("hello.html", {'msg_owner': msg_owner})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = {{msg_owner|safe}};
```

Comment: And what is msg_owner ?